# Linq-to-XML read XMLDocument in Loop

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Can Any one help me reading this XML and Looping through **`<MedicationDispensed>`**

I get this XML in **XMLDocument xdoc** (a dynamic Response)

```
    <Message xmlns="http://www.xxxx.org/schema/SCRIPT" version="008" release="001">
      <Header>
        <To Qualifier="ZZZ">T00000000021261</To>
        <From Qualifier="ZZZ">T00000000001000</From>
        <MessageID>1333375137258</MessageID>
        <RelatesToMessageID>19553495</RelatesToMessageID>
        <SentTime>2012-04-02T13:58:52</SentTime>
        <Security>
          <UsernameToken>
            <Username />
          </UsernameToken>
          <Sender>
            <SecondaryIdentification>JILITTQQPK</SecondaryIdentification>
            <TertiaryIdentification>RXHUB</TertiaryIdentification>
          </Sender>
          <Receiver>
            <SecondaryIdentification></SecondaryIdentification>
            <TertiaryIdentification />
          </Receiver>
        </Security>
        <Mailbox>
          <DeliveredID></DeliveredID>
        </Mailbox>
        <TestMessage>1</TestMessage>
      </Header>
      <Body>
        <RxHistoryResponse>
          <RxReferenceNumber>POCDH1</RxReferenceNumber>
          <PrescriberOrderNumber>POCDH1</PrescriberOrderNumber>
          <Response>
            <Approved />
          </Response>
          <Prescriber>
            <Identification>
              <NPI>xxxxxxxxx</NPI>
              <DEANumber>xxxxxx</DEANumber>
            </Identification>
            <Name>
              <LastName>xxxxxx</LastName>
              <FirstName>xxxxxxx</FirstName>
            </Name>
            <PhoneNumbers>
              <Phone>
                <Number>xxxxx</Number>
                <Qualifier>TE</Qualifier>
              </Phone>
            </PhoneNumbers>
          </Prescriber>
          <Patient>
            <PatientRelationship>1</PatientRelationship>
            <Name>
              <LastName>Schnur</LastName>
              <FirstName>Bert</FirstName>
              <MiddleName>L</MiddleName>
            </Name>
            <Gender>M</Gender>
            <DateOfBirth>1945-10-19</DateOfBirth>
          </Patient>
          <BenefitsCoordination>
            <PayerIdentification>
              <PayerID>PBM123</PayerID>
            </PayerIdentification>
            <PayerName>INSURANCE COMPANY NAME</PayerName>
            <CardholderID>MEMBERID</CardholderID>
            <CardholderName>PALTROW, BRUCE</CardholderName>
            <GroupID>B000000</GroupID>
            <Consent>Y</Consent>
            <PBMMemberID>B000000%111111110%001</PBMMemberID>
          </BenefitsCoordination>
          <MedicationDispensed>
            <DrugDescription>OXYCODONE W/APAP 5/325 TAB</DrugDescription>
            <DrugCoded>
              <ProductCode>00406051205</ProductCode>
              <ProductCodeQualifier>ND</ProductCodeQualifier>
            </DrugCoded>
            <Quantity>
              <Qualifier>00</Qualifier>
              <Value>60.0</Value>
              <CodeListQualifier>87</CodeListQualifier>
            </Quantity>
            <DaysSupply>15</DaysSupply>
            <LastFillDate>2012-04-02</LastFillDate>
            <Pharmacy>
              <Identification>
                <NCPDPID>1234567</NCPDPID>
              </Identification>
              <StoreName>WALGREENS #00000</StoreName>
              <Address>
                <AddressLine1>1 CENTRAL STREET</AddressLine1>
                <City>INDIANAPOLIS</City>
                <State>IN</State>
                <ZipCode>46201</ZipCode>
              </Address>
              <PhoneNumbers>
                <Phone>
                  <Number>8005551212</Number>
                  <Qualifier>TE</Qualifier>
                </Phone>
              </PhoneNumbers>
            </Pharmacy>
            <Prescriber>
              <Identification>
                <DEANumber>KR4184999</DEANumber>
              </Identification>
              <Name>
                <LastName>SMITH</LastName>
                <FirstName>JOHN</FirstName>
                <MiddleName>E</MiddleName>
              </Name>
              <Address>
                <AddressLine1>MERCY CLINIC</AddressLine1>
                <City>ST. PAUL</City>
                <State>MN</State>
                <ZipCode>55101</ZipCode>
              </Address>
            </Prescriber>
          </MedicationDispensed>
          <MedicationDispensed>
            <DrugDescription>HUMULIN 70/30 VIAL</DrugDescription>
            <DrugCoded>
              <ProductCode>00002871501</ProductCode>
              <ProductCodeQualifier>ND</ProductCodeQualifier>
            </DrugCoded>
            <Quantity>
              <Qualifier>00</Qualifier>
              <Value>10.0</Value>
              <CodeListQualifier>87</CodeListQualifier>
            </Quantity>
            <DaysSupply>30</DaysSupply>
            <LastFillDate>2012-04-01</LastFillDate>
            <Pharmacy>
              <Identification>
                <NCPDPID>1234567</NCPDPID>
              </Identification>
              <StoreName>WALGREENS #00000</StoreName>
              <Address>
                <AddressLine1>1 CENTRAL STREET</AddressLine1>
                <City>INDIANAPOLIS</City>
                <State>IN</State>
                <ZipCode>46201</ZipCode>
              </Address>
              <PhoneNumbers>
                <Phone>
                  <Number>8005551212</Number>
                  <Qualifier>TE</Qualifier>
                </Phone>
              </PhoneNumbers>
            </Pharmacy>
            <Prescriber>
              <Identification>
                <DEANumber>KR4184999</DEANumber>
              </Identification>
              <Name>
                <LastName>SMITH</LastName>
                <FirstName>JOHN</FirstName>
                <MiddleName>E</MiddleName>
              </Name>
              <Address>
                <AddressLine1>MERCY CLINIC</AddressLine1>
                <City>ST. PAUL</City>
                <State>MN</State>
                <ZipCode>55101</ZipCode>
              </Address>
            </Prescriber>
          </MedicationDispensed>
         Loop Continues
<MedicationDispensed>
<DrugDescription>OXYCODONE W/APAP 5/325 TAB</DrugDescription>
            <DrugCoded>
              <ProductCode>00406051205</ProductCode>
              <ProductCodeQualifier>ND</ProductCodeQualifier>
            </DrugCoded>
            <Quantity>
              <Qualifier>00</Qualifier>
              <Value>60.0</Value>
              <CodeListQualifier>87</CodeListQualifier>
            </Quantity>
            <DaysSupply>15</DaysSupply>
            <LastFillDate>2012-04-02</LastFillDate>
          <Pharmacy>
             ....Pharmacy Details
          </Pharmacy>
         <Prescriber>
             ... Prescriber Details
          </Prescriber>
        </MedicationDispensed>
        </RxHistoryResponse>
      </Body>
```

i need to read the Data in Loop for **`<MedicationDispensed>`**
I would like to do it through Linq-to-XML

Can any one give me a good start?

## Solution

I got my solution using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995686/query-nested-xml-elements-using-linq-to-xml-asp-net-c-sharp/9996410#9996410)

@Flowerking gave me a good start.

Comment: What language are you using, VB.NET or c#?  It makes a significant difference.

Comment: Please don't add "ASP.NET C#" and such to the ends of your titles. That's what the tags are for. Also, ASP.NET is not relevant to this question.

Comment: If you are doing a lot of querying of XML I would strongly suggest you move this to a VB.NET component as it's a hell of a lot easier than doing it in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.xxxx.org/schema/SCRIPT";

foreach(var elms in xdoc.Descendants(ns + "MedicationDispensed").Elements())
{
     Console.WriteLine(elms.Name + ":" + elms.Value.ToString());
}
```

If you have nested elements, then you need to iterate through them seperately,

```
foreach(var elms in xdoc.Descendants("MedicationDispensed").Elements())
{
    if(elms.HasElements)
    {
        foreach (var element in elms.Elements())
        {
            Console.WriteLine (element.Name + ":" + element.Value.ToString());
        }
    }
    else
    {
     Console.WriteLine(elms.Name + ":" + elms.Value.ToString());
     }
}
```

Comment: I think in this Foreach Loop we have to make some more changes to Get the Sub Block value. Like if you see  <Quantity>
          <Qualifier>00</Qualifier>
          <Value>60.0</Value>
          <CodeListQualifier>87</CodeListQualifier>
        </Quantity> like this. But your code give the Quantity As Quantity:0060.087

Comment: yes, my code is assuming non-nested elements, Could you please explain more on how your output should look like, as you need to recurse through the elements..

Comment: This should be one Single Object for Each Loop with all the Elements and Nested Element Values in it, If it is a Nested value (for Example Quantity) it should print QuantityQualifier: 00 QunaityValue:60.00 QuantityCodeListQualifier:87 so on..

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

Use XDocument.Parse() to load your document

```
XDocument myDoc = XDocument.Parse(doccontents);
```

Then use

```
XNamespace messagens = "http://www.xxxx.org/schema/SCRIPT";
IEnumerable<XElement> elements = from node in myDoc.Elements(messagens + "NedicationDispensed")
            select node;
```

which should return you an enumerable list of in-memory XElement objects.

Comment: myDoc.Elements returns null elements may be it should be myDoc.Descendants

Comment: It's at this point I suggest people start using VB.NET.  It handles the XML much better. :-)

Comment: @deadlyvices MedicationDispensed is not accessible to myDoc.Elements() , please check the xml structure. It has nothing to do with VB.NET or C#

Comment: Yes, I know that.  Thank You.  I made a mistake and should have put in Descendants instead of Elements.  If I'd done that I could have tested my code against the data he provided.  However I *don't* want to get to that point as I would be writing his code for him and I think that is not the point of this site.  I don't do things for strangers that I would normally charge them for.